# Update statement with lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a SQL table `Customer` with the following columns:

```
Customer_ID, Actioncode
```

I have another table with 1000+ actioncodes. Now I want to update the records in the `Customer` table with a unique code from the `actioncode` table.

I use this select statement at the moment:

```
update t 
set t.actiecode = (select top 1 actiecode from data_mgl_campagnemails_codes)
from data_mgl_campagnemails_transfer t;
```

The result is that all records are updated with the same `actiecode`. The `top 1` is responsible for that. When I remove that I got an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

This seems logical. How can I do this without using a cursor?

There is no relationship between the `Customer` and `Code` table.

Table structure:

```
data_mgl_campagnemails_transfer
id  customer_id  actioncode  actioncode_id
1   1                 -           -
2   3                 -           -
3   4                 -           -

data_mgl_campagnemails_codes
id  actioncode active
1     TTTT   
2     RRRR
3     VVVV
4     RRRW
```

The result should be:

```
data_mgl_campagnemails_transfer
id  customer_id  actioncode  actioncode_id
1   1               TTTT           1
2   3               RRRR           2
3   4               VVVV           3

data_mgl_campagnemails_codes
id  actioncode active
1     TTTT       YES
2     RRRR       YES
3     VVVV       YES
4     RRRW
```

Comment: How do you determine what actioncode should be set for each row in the customer table if the two tables are not related?

Comment: And also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik, I use a SQL table.

Comment: @jpw. Any unused code in the data_mgl_campagnemails_codes tabel which isn't used is fine. After updating this table I want to update the data_mgl_campagnemails table and flag all the codes that are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a bit tricky using a single statement, because SQL Server likes to optimize things.  So the obvious:

```
update t 
    set t.actiecode = (select top 1 actiecode 
                       from data_mgl_campagnemails_codes
                       order by newid()
                      )
    from data_mgl_campagnemails_transfer t;
```

Also doesn't work.  One method is to enumerate things and use a `join` or correlated subquery:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from data_mgl_campagnemails_transfer t
     ),
     a as (
      select a.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from data_mgl_campagnemails_codes a
     )
update t
    set t.actiecode = (select top 1 actiecode from a)
    from t join
         a
         on t.seqnum = a.seqnum;
```

Another way is to "trick" SQL Server into running the correlated subquery more than once.  I think something like this:

```
update t 
    set t.actiecode = (select top 1 actiecode 
                       from data_mgl_campagnemails_codes
                       where t.CustomerId is not null -- references the outer table but really does nothing
                       order by newid()
                      )
    from data_mgl_campagnemails_transfer t;
```

Comment: Tnx for your suggestion. I tried the second method, but I also got the same actioncode on every record.

Comment: The third method worked perfectly! Tnx! Could there be any performance issues with this solution?

Comment: @Hodia . . . None of these will be really efficient, but for smallish data they should be fine.

Comment: Tnx for your solution!